# Join 3 datatables in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatable, dataset

I have the following 3 data-tables:

```
    Table1 
    --------------------------------
    ScheduleID | Name  | Details
    -----------------------------
    1             S1     schedule details 
    2             S2     schedule details
    3             S3     schedule details
    4             S4     schedule details


    Table2
    ------------------------------
    ScheduleGroupID  | ScheduleID 
    ------------------------------
    1                      1      
    1                      2    
    1                      3     
    2                      4     

    Table3
    -----------------------------------------------
    ScheduleGroupID   | Description  | ScheduleCount
    ------------------------------------------------
    1                    Urgent             3
    2                    Non-urgent         1


    Expected Result
    ---------------------------------------------------------------
    ScheduleID | Name | Details | ScheduleGroupID |   Description
    -------------------------------------------------------------
    1             S1       5             1         Urgent(row from table3) 
    2             S2       5             1         Urgent(row from table3) 
    3             S3       5             1         Urgent(row from table3) 
    4             S4       5             2         Non-urgent(from table3)
```

So i have three datatables and would like to merge them into one table in order to produce the expected result shown above. How can this be done within c#? I assume i would have to use LINQ but don't have much experience with it.

Comment: Entity Framework and LINQ, you will need an Entity Framework Model or have you done that? You will get a Navigation Property on the tables

Comment: @MarkHomer, he doesn't need one there are many ways to do this that don't require either, though that is probably the simplest

Comment: @MikeT are you able to provide more info on these other ways, I'm trying to avaoid using Entity Framework

Comment: @MikeT no he doesn't but why wouldn't he? Why dont you want to use Entity Framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this create a class like below

```
public class TestClass
{
    public int ScheduleID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public int ScheduleGroupID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And write the query like this

```
List<TestClass> colection = (from x in db.Table1
                join y in db.Table2 on x.ScheduleID  equals y.ScheduleID
                join z in db.Table3 on y.ScheduleGroupID equals z.ScheduleGroupID
                select new CityClass
                {
                   ScheduleID = x.ScheduleID,
                   Name = x.Name,
                   Details  = x.Details,
                   ScheduleGroupID = y.ScheduleGroupID,
                   Description = z.Description
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! This works, you responded first so have marked yours as the answer for that reason

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it is `DataTable` you could `join` this way.

```
    var result = from s in schedule.AsEnumerable()
    join sg in  schedulegroup.AsEnumerable() on s.Field<int>("ScheduleID") equals sg.Field<int>("ScheduleID") 
    join g in groups.AsEnumerable() on sg.Field<int>("ScheduleGroupID") equals g.Field<int>("ScheduleGroupID") 
    select new 
    {
        ScheduleID = s.Field<int>("ScheduleID"),
        Name = s.Field<string>("Name"),
        Details = s.Field<int>("Details"),
        ScheduleGroupID = sg.Field<int>("ScheduleGroupID"),
        Description = g.Field<string>("Description")
    };
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sBrSeu)

Comment: This works perfectly and was the method i've implemented.

Answer (score 1):

The question you are asking is 2 parts

first connecting to the database

As you have stated that you want to avoid EnitiyFramework

some of the other options are

- [LinqToSql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384429.aspx):this will function fairly similar to EF with out all
  the overhead of the full framework
- if you want to go back and be even more old school you have datasets
  which can be configured to be more useful than a generic [dataset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/04y282hb.aspx)
- or even more old school [SQLCommands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) and [datareaders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx)

once you have the data

then the best method of querying is LinqToObjects

```
var results = from a in Table1
              join b in Table2 on a.ID equals b.ID
              join c in Table3 on b.ID2 equals c.ID2
              //create a anonymous type or better if you want the results to persist create a normal object
              select new{ a.Column1, a.Column2, b.Column1, c.Column1};
```

failing that you can do it via code
eg

```
//firstly build up a key index to make the matching easier
var t1Dic = new Dictionary<int,DataRow>();
foreach(var row in table1.Rows)
{
    t1Dic.Add(row[IDCol],row);
}
var t2Dic = new Dictionary<int,DataRow>();
foreach(var row in table2.Rows)
{
    t2Dic.Add(row[IDCol],row);
}
//next run though your linking table and add them to your results table
var results = new DataTable();
foreach(var row in table3.Rows)
{
    var r = results.NewRow();
    r[YourColumnName1] = t1Dic[row[Id1Col][YourColumnName1];
    r[YourColumnName2] = t1Dic[row[Id1Col][YourColumnName2];
    r[YourColumnName3] = t2Dic[row[Id2Col][YourColumnName3];
    r[YourColumnName4] = t2Dic[row[Id2Col][YourColumnName4];
    r[YourColumnName5] = t2Dic[row[Id2Col][YourColumnName5];
}
```

EF and Linq are definitely the easiest method though

Comment: Thanks MikeT, if only EF was an option but unfortunately not on this occassion. I will take your answer into consideration the next time i face a similar challenge! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Bringing direct relationship between tables would make easier for the program to retrieve data. If EF is used, results can be retrieved by writing a single line.

Above tables can be changed to use only 2 tables .
You can add another column in table1 as schedulegroupID which would be foreign key to schedulegroup table

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.schedule
ADD schedulegroupId INT

ALTER TABLE dbo.schedule
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_scheduleGroup
FOREIGN KEY (schedulegroupId)
REFERENCES scheduleGroup(ID)
```

In this way, there would be direct relationship between the tables which makes it easier to write both SQL and LINQ queries.

```
--SQL Query 
SELECT * FROM dbo.schedule s INNER JOIN dbo.scheduleGroup sg ON s.schedulegroupid = sg.ID
//LINQ Query    
var query = db.schedules.Include("scheduleGroup").ToList();
```

Below code would show the first line of the required results.

```
Console.WriteLine(query[0].Name.ToString() + "," +  query[0].Details.ToString() + "," +  query[0].schedulegroupId.Value.ToString() + ","
                + query[0].scheduleGroup.Description.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I get your point!
I also believe that if i changed the way the tables or stored procedure were written it would have not brought this problem in the first place, but these cannot be changed. I appreciate your feedback though. Let me know if you know any good resources to learn LINQ querying.